# Iteration over dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary as below and a function called "multi" that takes numbers as arguments. The function will multiply each values of a key in dictionary by numbers that been input as argument. So what im trying to do is, I would like to iterate the function "multi" so it calculate certain range of "i"

```
a_dict={'cms': 123, 'dms': 133, 'test': 111}

def multi(i):
    for key, values in a_dict.items():
        values=values*i
        return (key,values)
multi(2)
```

Here is the example of iteration function that i made

```
def iterate_(start,end,range_):
    box=[]
    for a in range (start,end+1,range_):
        data=multi(a)
        box.append(data)
    return box
```

Here is the output:

```
iterate_(10,50,10)

Output: [('cms', 1230), ('cms', 2460), ('cms', 3690), ('cms', 4920), ('cms', 6150)]
```

The return result will only return the 1st key of the dictionary only. Im expecting that it returns all dictionary's keys with the updated values for each iteration.

I did try change "return" to "print", manage to get all the keys with the update result, but got an empty list.

```
a_dict={'cms': 123, 'dms': 133, 'test': 111}

def multi(i):
    for key, values in a_dict.items():
        values=values*i
        print (key,values)

def iterate_(start,end,range_):
    box=[]
    for a in range (start,end+1,range_):
        data=multi(a)
        box.append(data)
        a+=5
    return box
    
iterate_(10,50,10)

Output:
cms 1230
dms 1330
test 1110
cms 2460
dms 2660
test 2220
cms 3690
dms 3990
test 3330
cms 4920
dms 5320
test 4440
cms 6150
dms 6650
test 5550
[23]:
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Why is that `a+=5` inside your iterate_ function?

Comment: forgot to delete that, I have replaced that with range (start,end,range_)

Answer (score 1):

Using return in multi function() your loop breakes in first iteration, so it only returns the first key,value pair of your dict.
Using print() instead of return it return nothing, that is why your list is empty in second case

Here is a solution. Notice that we use 'extend' in iterate_ function:

```
a_dict={'cms': 123, 'dms': 133, 'test': 111}

def multi(i):
    return [(key, i*value) for key, value in a_dict.items()]

def iterate_(start,end,range_):
    box=[]
    for a in range (start,end+1,range_):
        data=multi(a)
        box.extend(data)
        a+=5
    return box

Example:

>>> iterate_(10,50,10)

[('cms', 1230), ('dms', 1330), ('test', 1110), ('cms', 2460), ('dms', 2660), ('test', 2220), ('cms', 3690), ('dms', 3990), ('test', 3330), ('cms', 4920), ('dms', 5320), ('test', 4440), ('cms', 6150), ('dms', 6650), ('test', 5550)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `multi` function:
Here is the solution:

```
def multi(i):
  for key in a_dict:
    a_dict[key]*=i
  return list(a_dict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to collect all the elements you are modifying inside `multi` and return them together. With your two approaches you were:

- Returning the value of the first iteration, ignoring the rest
- Just printing in the console the result of the operation over the entire dictionary, but never collecting/returning them.

So try to change multi to the following:

```
def multi(i):
    result = [] # Defining a list to accumulate results
    for key, values in a_dict.items():
        result.append((key,values*i)) # Adding results of each iteration
    return result # Returning the list
```